# Multiplied background and Z-Index Problem

Tags: css, z-index, mix-blend-mode

I have a list of thumbnails with a title on top of them. The background of the title should be multiplied on the image behind, but not the text.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="thumbslink">
  <figure>
    <img src="imagelink" />
  </figure>
  <div class="title-wrapper">
    <div class="title">
      <span class="background"></span>
      <p> Title </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.thumbslink {
  position: relative;
}

a.thumbslink figure {
 aspect-ratio: 3/2;
 position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div.title-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div.title {
  position: relative;
}

div.title p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

div.title span.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

But the `<span class="background">` element keeps sitting on top of everything, multiplying red color over the image *and* the title, even if its z-index says it should be **behind** the title and the title element is rendered after the background span.

Working with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements didn't solve the problem.

What can I do?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this because the code currently provided does not produce the effect you are claiming. Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/dyKzevd) using your provided code that shows the text is on top of the red overlay and there seems to be no effect between the overlay's `mix-blend-mode` and the title text.

Comment: @EssXTee Something I forgot: There is a ```.title-wrapper``` element around the title in order to make the background size stick to the size of the title. Here is the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/emollini/pen/VwdzNjr). Sorry I forgot that in my source code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite a full explanation as I don't know enough about the relationship between `z-index` and parent/child elements.

So one simple fix to deal with annoying `z-index` issues is to assign a value of **-1** to an element to force it to a lower priority. However, doing that by itself would cause your red background element to go behind ***all*** other elements on the page. So in order to keep it above the image, we need the parent element of our red background to also have its `z-index` set to a value that would keep it above the image.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

figure { margin: 0; }

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

div.title-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

div.title p {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

div.title span.background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="thumbslink">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" />
  </figure>
  <div class="title-wrapper">
    <div class="title">
      <span class="background"></span>
      <p> Title </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```